# Upload a text file on hipchat room using Curl

Tags: curl, protractor, hipchat

I am using bash script to run the Protractor automation script. I am getting results in the text file. Now I want to upload that file on the hipchat room.

I am able to get the the content of the file but I want to upload actual text file on the hipchat. Please help!

Here is my curl command which displays file content on the hipchat room:

```
curl  -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain'-F "file=@target/screenshots/AutomationReport.txt" https://dev.hipchat.com/v2/room/3157124/notification?auth_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong API to share a file. As per the [official docs](https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/share_file_with_room) at HiPCHat the correct way to share a file in a room is

```
POST /v2/room/{room_id_or_name}/share/file
```

For Complete usage guide check [here](https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/share_file_with_room) 
Let me know if that works

EDIT1: The auth_token has to be passed as earlier. The request will look something like below

`POST /v2/room/3157124/share/file?auth_token`

Comment: Hi Aditya - I tried :                                                                                        curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' "file=@target/screenshots/AutomationReport.txt" https://dev.hipchat.com/v2/room/<roomid>/share/file  But getting following error message: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Authenticated requests only. See https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/auth for more information.",
    "type": "Unauthorized"
  }
}   Can you please let me know how do I need to set up API, Thanks

Comment: You have to pass the `?auth_token` as you were doing it earlier and also replace the roomID with the one you have in earlier request. I have updated the answer accordingly